# FAB Button using on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, floating-action-button

I have a problem. I'm working an android project and I want to using FAB button in ActionBar. Just like ActionBar item. Is it possible or impossible? I'm looking for a lot tutorial but I've never seen just like I want.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using toolbar instead of action bar, use custom layout for toolbar

Comment: What you want you can achieve using bottomAppBar.
This is the example:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomappbar